# Laravel get two value array count from controller in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, laravel, charts, highcharts

I have a query that allows to calculate the count with a condition if gender= "mal" and "female".

```
$users[] =  User:: whereIn('gender',array('mal', 'female'))->count()->get();
return view('/',compact('users[]'));
```

These count are displayed in a bar chart

```
function drawStacked() {
var genders[] = {{ $users[] }}
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Element', '', { role: 'style' }, { role: 'annotation' } ],
    ['Mal', '#000', genders[0]],
    ['Female', '#000', genders[1]],
 ]);
}
```

but he only shows me count of gender **mal**

Comment: I don't think you understand what whereIn does. You only get one collection which then is counted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute two queries:

```
$maleCount = User::where('gender', 'male')->count();
$femaleCount = User::where('gender', 'female')->count();
return view('/', compact('maleCount', 'femaleCount'));
```

Answer (score 0):

it's very well for the solution of Alexey Mezenin , but i would like to regrouping in one where and return array and show it in javascript for example : `genders[0] for mal and genders[1] for female`

Answer (score 0):

You need just put the results of Alexey's solution into an array like:

```
$counts = [
    'male' => User::where('gender', 'male')->count(),
    'female' => User::where('gender', 'female')->count()
];

return view('/', compact('counts'));
```

Then you can access them in you view like:

```
$counts['male']
// or
$counts['female']
```